# NPOCO con tablas relacionadas + tabla detalle con relacion a otra tabla.! ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

resulta que estoy usando el microORM  NPOCO con excelentes resultados.. solo que me eh topado ahora con algo que no puedo resolver..  la relacion de uno a muchos no tengo problemas a la hora de obtener un resultado por ejempo  una factura con su detalle... el asunto es que ahora tengo una clase Rutas  que se relaciona a Ciudades (inicio y termino) de modo uno a uno, asi como con ParadasRutas (detalle que es relacion de uno a muchos, una ruta tiene varias paradas. Ademas tiene el id de la ciudad donde se hara una parada  y la cual pues esta relacionada con Ciudades de uno a uno...  les dejo el codigo.. no se como poder integrar el INCLUDE con ParadasRutas

```
public static Ruta GetById(int id)
{
   var result = new Ruta();
   try
   {
      using (IDatabase db = DBContext.GetInstance())
      {
         result = db.Query<Ruta>().Include(x => x.CiudadInicio).Include(x => x.CiudadFin)
                       .IncludeMany(x => x.ParadaRuta).Include(x => x.Ciudad)
                       .Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

         // Trato de hacer el include de Ciudad con ParadasRutas y
         // Aqui marca error -->>>  .IncludeMany(x => x.ParadaRuta).Include(x => x.Ciudad)
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**RESUELTO..!**

Solved..!

```
result = db.Query<Ruta>().Include(x => x.CiudadInicio).Include(x => x.Ciudadfin)
                             .Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

// ya que instancie paradar ruta como lista en el constructor de la clase Ruta,
// puedo acceder a paradas ruta y asignarle los valores...
// normalmente se haria con un IncludeMany, pero ya que paradas ruta va relacionada
// con la tabla ciudad, includemany no puede hacer include de otra tabla, por eso
// lo integre en otro query, teniendo acceso a la clase detalle ;)
result.ParadasRuta= db.Query<ParadasRuta>().Include(x => x.Ciudad)
                               .Where(x => x.IdRuta == id).ToList();
```